# ES6 disallowed variable names - why are the names 'let' and 'const' behaving differently?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was playing around with unadvisable variable declarations and came to the observations below.

---

Defining a variable with the name `'let'`, like so:

```js
let let = 7;
```

somewhat unsurprisingly leads to the error: `SyntaxError: let is disallowed as a lexically bound name`.

---

Attempting to do the same with the variable name `'const'`, like so:

```js
let const = 7;
```

leads to the different error:  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'`.

---

Looking at the specs, section [13.3.1.1 Static Semantics: Early Errors](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations-static-semantics-early-errors) disallows `'let'` as a variable name in this type of declarations (without mentioning `'const'`).

This is more of a curiosity, but what is happening behind the scenes, which would make `'let'` merely be seen as a disallowed variable name while making `'const'` be interpreted as a token?

---

*(Incidentally `var let = 7` appears to be syntactically correct JavaScript, while `var const = 7` also leads to the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'`.*)

Comment: `const` is a [reserved word](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words), `let` is not.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling! Looking at the [ES5 specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2), which already include `const` as a reserved word but not `let`, I presume that `let` was left out for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: [Digging a bit more into it](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words), the `let` declaration actually also leads to an error in strict mode (`SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically for backwards compatibility reason. Like Felix said [const is a reserved word](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words) - for a [while now](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.1).

Code like the below is legal JavaScript (in loose mode) since `let` is just a word:

```js
var let = 50;
console.log(let);
```

Note that indeed when strict mode was added `let` was reserved inside it:

> The following tokens are also considered to be FutureReservedWords when they occur within strict mode code (see 10.1.1).

Reserves let.

As a fun fact [const](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf) is reserved in the ES3 specification too.